# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded when compiling

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm getting `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` when compiling my TypeScript project using `tsc`.

```
/home/my_project/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsc.js:94444
                throw e;
                ^

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at structuredTypeRelatedToWorker (/home/my_project/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsc.js:53088:51)
    at structuredTypeRelatedTo (/home/my_project/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsc.js:53084:30)
    at recursiveTypeRelatedTo (/home/my_project/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsc.js:53055:53)
    at isRelatedTo (/home/my_project/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsc.js:52648:34)
    at isPropertySymbolTypeRelated (/home/my_project/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsc.js:53641:24)
    at propertyRelatedTo (/home/my_project/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsc.js:53673:31)
    at propertiesRelatedTo (/home/my_project/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsc.js:53861:43)
    at structuredTypeRelatedToWorker (/home/my_project/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsc.js:53460:34)
    at structuredTypeRelatedTo (/home/my_project/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsc.js:53084:30)
    at recursiveTypeRelatedTo (/home/my_project/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsc.js:53055:53)
```

I've read on other thread that this error could be caused by recursive type annotation in the source files or wrong call to a function. The problem is I don't know which part of my code is causing this error and using the `--verbose` options also doesn't help.

How can I know which part of my code that causes this error? Can I turn on a more *verbose* output from `tsc` to narrow down my search?

### Update

I just found out that this issue only existed when I use `strict: true` in my `tsconfig.json`. When I disable the strict mode, the error is gone.

References:

- https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38198

Answer (score 1):

As per my last update about disabling strict mode in TypeScript, I consider the problem to be resolved. But I still wanted to know how can I enable strict mode in the future and figure out why I', getting the error above.